# visual studio and linking to pre-compilied binaries (lib / dll)

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, dll, lib

Some libraries are available to download as pre-compiled binaries, usually in specific architecture (x32 or x64) but I have also noticed that some pre-compiled binaries are splitted based on visual studio version, for example: vc17_x64. Let's assume that I use visual studio 2019. Does it mean that I have to use binaries precompiled for vc2019 or build a library from source when apropriate version is not available ? It's not clear for me because some pre-compilied binaries don't contain information about visual studio version.

Answer (score 0):

If a pre-compiled library has Visual Studio version info you **should** use that version of Visual Studio to work with the library. This is not always the case though, as often enough happens that an older (with respect to VS version) library contains code that is a **subset** of the newer VS's header and runtime SDK files (.NET, C/C++, Windows SDK, etc). The other way around, when the library is newer can also work but it's **far** less frequent. You can try, if it doesn't work for your particular library and VS version then you should consider matching versions, rebuilding not always works for the same reasons of code changes.
If a library doesn't contain VS version info then it's reasonable to assume that it's portable/compatible up to operating system (Windows, Linux, etc) and programming language version (C++ 11,  C++ 14, C# 7, C# 8, etc). However, VS version comes into play here as well, not every VS runs in every Windows, neither it supports the same runtimes, SDKs, and language(s) version. You should **always** check the library documentation for recommended working environment, if this info doesn't exist then it's trial and error and/or community consulting.